# Multilingual site with rtl and ltr direction

Tags: php, css, yii

How should i implement  site with two language that one language direction is rtl.
should i create form-rtl.css and main-rtl.css and check user language and if user have selected a rtl language i have to add this form-rtl and main-rtl.css files after yii css files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction should be set in HTML (using the `dir` attribute), since it is an inherent property of a writing system, rather than casual presentation feature.

Some style settings may need to be set with due attention to directionality, so it makes sense to have separate CSS files for settings for RTL writing and for settings for LTR writing. But probably most of the CSS settings can be kept in one file.

So you could have something like this for an Arabic-language page:

```
<html lang=ar dir=rtl>
...
<link rel=stylesheet href=common.css> <!-- overall settings -->
<link rel=stylesheet href=rtl.css>    <!-- settings specific to RTL writing -->
<link rel=stylesheet href=ar.css>     <!-- settings specific to Arabic language,
                                           e.g. font family settings -->
```